# VBA: Calculating the value at every row, but variables change depending on one column

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I would like to create a simple formula to calculate the net change on a certain row, and print it in the same row (column H). But what I plug into the formula will depend on the value at each row's column A.

This is the code that I tried:

```vb
Sub totalPnL()
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If Range("A2:A" & LR).Value = "WIN" Then
        Range("H2:H" & LR).Formula = "=ABS(D2-F2)*G2"

    ElseIf Range("A2:A" & LR).Value = "LOSS" Then
        Range("H2:H" & LR).Formula = "=-ABS(D2-E2)*G2"
    
    End If
        
    Range("T2") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("H:H"))

End Sub
```

I feel something is wrong with the If statement, but I'm not sure how to edit it

Thanks for all the help

Comment: The statement `Range("A2:A" & LR).Value = "WIN"` cannot work unless `LR` is `2`. Do you understand why?

Comment: `=SWITCH(A2,"WIN",ABS(D2-F2)*G2,"LOSS",-ABS(D2-E2)*G2,0)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the comment a formula will be easier and quicker but if you want to have your code "fixed" then the following code would do it.

```
Sub totalPnL()
    Dim LR As Long, i As Long
    
    LR = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    
        ' the original statement
        ' Range("A2:A" & LR).Value = "WIN"
        ' cannot work as Range("A2:A" & LR) will be an array in case LR > 2
        ' in this case you have to loop
        ' AGAIN: usage of a formula will be better
    
        For i = 2 To LR
            If Range("A" & i).Value = "WIN" Then
                Range("H" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(RC[-4]-RC[-2])*RC[-1]"

            ElseIf Range("A" & i).Value = "LOSS" Then
                Range("H" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(RC[-4]-RC[-2])*RC[-1]"
    
            End If
        Next i
        
    Range("T2") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("H:H"))

End Sub
```

To make the code easier to read you could use a `Select` statement

```
For i = 2 To LR
    Select Case Range("A" & i).Value
        Case "WIN"
            Range("H" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(RC[-4]-RC[-2])*RC[-1]"
        Case "LOSS"
            Range("H" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(RC[-4]-RC[-2])*RC[-1]"
    End Select
Next i
```

Another formula you could use would be
`=IF(A2="WIN";1;(IF(A2="LOSS";-1)))*ABS(D2-F2)*G2`